# Sorting/accessing through an array of nested hashes

Tags: ruby, hash

I have an array of hashes with names and ages:

```
array = [ {"bill" => 12}, {"tom" => 13}, {"pat" => 14} ]
```

I realize that, by calling the `first` method, this happens:

```
array.first # => {"bill" => 12}
```

Without defining a class, I'd like to do:

```
array.first.name # => "bill"
```

How can I do that?

Doing:

```
def name
  array[0].keys
end
```

will define a private method, which can't be called on the receiver.

Comment: Your requirement is contradictory. Calling a method on an object means that method is defined on the object or its class. But you are expecting to do it without that. Why can't you define a method on Hash?

Comment: Embrace classes in Ruby! It makes a lot of things clean, concise, and readable!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your Array `array` consists of Hashes, when you do `array.first` a Hash is returned `{"bill" => 12}`.

You can now define a method `Hash#name` that can be applied to `array.first`
(a Hash)

Here:

```
class Hash
  def name
    self.keys.first
  end
end

array.first.name
# => "bill"

#to print all names
array.each{|a| puts a.name}
# bill
# tom
# pat

# or collect them in an Array
array.map(&:name)
#  => ["bill", "tom", "pat"]
```

Comment: This accomplishes the goal, but doing this in “real” code is a terrible idea as every Hash now gets the `name` method even though it makes no sense nearly all the time.

Answer (score 1):

You have:

```
h = array.first #=> {"bill" => 12} 
h.class         #=> Hash
```

so if you want to create a method `first`, such that:

```
h.name #=> "bill"
```

you must define `name` on the class of its receiver (`h`), which is `Hash`.  @shivam has shown you how to that, but (as @AndrewMarshall points out in a comment) that it pollutes the class `Hash`. A better way is to use `Refinements`.

[Refinements](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/doc/syntax/refinements_rdoc.html) was an experimental addition to v2.0, then modified and made permanent in v2.1. It provides a way to avoid "monkey-patching" by providing "a way to extend a class locally".

We can do that as follows. First, `refine` `Hash` within a module `M`:

```
module M
  refine Hash do
    def name
      keys.first
    end
  end
end
```

The refinement has no effect until the keyword `using` is invoked on the module:

```
h = {"bill" => 12} 

puts h.name
  #-> undefined method `name' for {"bill"=>12}:Hash  (NoMethodError)
```

After activating the refinement we can invoke `name` on `h`:

```
using M
h.name
  #-> bill
```

The refinement applies to the remainder of the file, but does not apply to to code in other files. Suppose we were to add the following to the present file:

```
class A
  def greeting(h)
    puts "Hello, #{h.name}"
  end
end
```

Then:

```
A.new.greeting({"bill" => 12})
  #-> Hello, bill
```